# Delete old artifacts in jenkins using pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, devops

Sometimes I got some failed builds, why?

```
stage('Clear old artifacts'){
   bat """cd D:/Jenkins/jobs/foobar/builds && for /f "skip=3 eol=: delims=" %%F in ('dir /b /ad-ld /o-d *') do @rmdir /S /Q %%F || dir /ad-ld /o-d *"""
}
```

Comment: you would need to post the console log for a failed build for this to be answerable, i think.

Comment: Problem is only with this stage, sometimes it returns exit code 1

Answer (score 0):

I forgot about my solution :)

```
stage('Clear old artifacts'){
    bat """set errorlevel=0 && cd D:/Jenkins/jobs/xxx/builds && for /f "skip=3 eol=: delims=" %%F in ('dir /b /ad-ld /o-d *') do @rmdir /S /Q %%F"""
}
```